# html5- mismatch in key value in session and local storage

Tags: html

Is the local storage stores all keys and values in common. ie., if i use a key called **counter** in one page and same key **counter** is used in another page to store a value, whether first one overwrites the next one??? how it works actually??

Comment: sorry Jim for late reply. what u referred as container?

Answer (score 0):

i found it. for each domain you can have only one key with a name. for example: for 199.63.166.222/localwebsite.html , it stores a key name **Name** , and if i use same key in 199.63.166.222/private.html this will overwrite the value previously stored from localwebsite.html ; this is due to both pages are from same domain.